# Which vim configuration makes green line on the screen when I'm not looking?

Tags: microsoft-windows

It's only been a few days since I configured vim, installed WSL2, etc. Everything was alright, but today was different. I opened vim, and began coding. My code was kind of long so I couldn't see the full code on the screen. When I go up to see the rest of my code, I saw green stripes on almost every line that was empty.

To make it go away I had to type something on it and then erase it. When I was done, I scrolled down to see the other part of my code and there they were again! I googled: "Green stripes on empty space vim" but with no success. I would like to know which vim configuration does that so I can stop it.

[image]

Comment: Does it disappear when you press `<C-l>` (control + lower case letter L)?

Comment: It does.  How can I make it stop showing up?

Comment: Yeah, don't know. `<C-l>` redraws the screen, so it sounds like a rendering error or the like, rather than a plugin doing this intentionally. I *suspect* this may be a bug somewhere (but that's really just a guess!) You can try following [How do I debug my vimrc file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/51) and see if it's triggered by a specific setting or some such.

Comment: It's my vim setting, but how come it only appeared today?

Comment: The configuration wasn't someone else's, it was my dad's and he use it everyday at work. How come he doesn't have that problem?

Comment: Different environment? Different Vim version? Different apps/libraries installed? Different cosmic rays? Modern systems are really complex with a lot of moving parts, and the amount of permutations the "same" system can have is enormous. I don't know if there's something in the config that could be the cause of this, but it's the obvious place to start looking. Maybe it's a bug triggered only on a specific version if you have 2 specific settings enabled? You never know... The problem may not even be in Vim; these kind of problems tend to be really hard to diagnose :-(

Comment: So if I can't diagnose it, I ignore it?

Comment: Yeah, you either learn to live with it or try to fix it :-(

Comment: Usually I see this with TERM issues

Comment: What is TERM issues?